# Fragment not getting inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner in android and testing the RecyclerView.Following is my Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.recyclerviewtest.RecyclerTestActivity" >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
  >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is my MainActivity.java class

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new      RecyclerTestActivity()).commit();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
}
}
}
```

And here is the main_activity_xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

 <fragment 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/container"      
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

But while attaching the fragment in the main activity in the line:

```
 transaction.replace(R.id.container, new     RecyclerTestActivity()).commit();
```

I am getting the error:

```
The method replace is not applicable for (int,RecyclerTestActivity)
```

Can someone please help me in this.

Edit: The code for RecyclerTestActivity Fragment is :

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class RecyclerTestActivity extends Fragment {
private Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerview;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)     {
    View Layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recycler_test,container,false);
    recyclerview=(RecyclerView)Layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    adapter=new Adapter(getActivity(), getdata());
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return Layout;
}

public List<Information> getdata()
{
    List<Information> items = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] data ={R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
    String[] content={"One","Two","Three"};

    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        Information current = new Information();
        current.desc=content[i];
        current.number=data[i];
        items.add(current);
    }

    return items;

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line: 
`transaction.replace(R.id.container, new RecyclerTestActivity()).commit();`

This should be `transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();`
Instead of a `Fragment`, you are having an `Activity`.

Also in your xml, you are using `<fragment>` tag. Instead use some layout like `<FrameLayout>` or `<LinearLayout>`

UPDATE:

In your `MainActivity` you are using `android.app.FragmentTransaction;`. But your Fragment is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`. You can't do this. You have to either completely use the AppCompat_v4 or not. Use `android.app.Fragment` instead.

Or I would strongly suggest your `MainActivity` extend `FragmentActivity` and you use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..RecyclerTestActivity is already a fragment..I have updated its code in my question..

Comment: @ghostrider Could you post the code of RecyclerTestActivity ?

Comment: @ghostrider I have updated my answer, either use `android.app.Fragment` or use `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Henry..Can you please highlight the difference between supportFragment and just Fragment if possible.

Comment: `Fragment` can run only on devices on or above API11. But support Fragment will run from API4 or above. Always a better idea to use Support Library, not only just for fragments. They are used for backward compatibility

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93299/discussion-between-ghostrider-and-henry).

Answer (score 1):

Use this in **main_activity_xml**:

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">
</FrameLayout>
```

Than in **MainActivity.java** replace current fragment with (change `YourFragment` with `RecyclerTestActivity`) :

```
Fragment fr;
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fr = new YourFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fr);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Remeber to import:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

`YourFragment.java` is a class that extends `Fragment` (android.app.Fragment) check here [Fragment Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Fragment class example (Google Docs example):

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

So your code is:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
    Fragment fr;
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fr = new  RecyclerTestActivity();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
}
}
}
```

**main_activity_layout.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your **RecyclerTestActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.recyclerviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class RecyclerTestActivity extends Fragment {
private Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerview;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)     {
    View Layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recycler_test,container,false);
    recyclerview=(RecyclerView)Layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    adapter=new Adapter(getActivity(), getdata());
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return Layout;
}

public List<Information> getdata()
{
    List<Information> items = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] data ={R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
    String[] content={"One","Two","Three"};

    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        Information current = new Information();
        current.desc=content[i];
        current.number=data[i];
        items.add(current);
    }

    return items;

}

}
```

Comment: It is giving the error : "cannot convert from RecyclerTestActivity to fragment". RecyclerTestActivity is already a fragment whose code I have updated in my question above.Please help

Comment: @ghostrider have you read full my answer? you need to use app.Fragment not v4.app.Fragment

Comment: I've update answer with your code, check it now and enjoy :D

Answer (score 0):

An Activity is no Fragment therefore you can't use it as a Fragment.. You need to create a Fragment to add it to your FragmentManager. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html).